# ajax, setRequestHeader(), Content-Type, application/x-www-form-urlencoded and charset

Tags: javascript, ajax, character-encoding

I am having trouble understanding how to set the charset when the
content type is not text/html, text/plain, or text/xml, but is application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type instead.

Given this (simplified) javascript code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

If I **do not** explicitly set the encoding,

```
xhr.open('POST', 'serv.php', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

firebug tells me that the content
type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=**UTF-8**."

If I set the charset to ISO-8859-1 for instance,

```
xhr.open('POST', 'serv.php', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

firebug **still** tells me "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=**UTF-8**."

If I try something like

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

then it respects the charset.

In all the cases the send() method goes like this:

```
xhr.send('id=9&name=Yoda');
```

Why doesn't it honor the charset I specify if the Content-Type is x-www-form-urlencoded?

NOTE: I am using ISO-8859-1 just as an example. My goal is to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` mime type does not support parameters (such as `charset`). If you look at [this section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#url-encoded-form-data) of the HTML5 spec, you will see how charset is determined (it's complicated). In particular, there is a note at the bottom of the section mentioning how charset cannot be specified as a parameter to the mime type.

Comment: interesting, so how do we ensure a particular collation is used/enforce a particular collation?! do we have to use a form to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
```